# Access SQL: select only records with one occurrence in combined field

Tags: sql, ms-access, unique

I have an access DB with address information in several tables.
I created an SQL statement to get the combined information out in a query, and that works.

My next step would be to get only the records with only one occurrence in the db but I can't seem to get it to work.

My code so far would return: (example)

```
combination lat/long postal_code letter_part house_number street name
123123               1234        aa          1            teststreet
123124               1234        aa          3            teststreet
123124               1234        aa          5            teststreet
123124               1234        aa          7            teststreet
123124               1234        aa          9            teststreet
123125               1234        aa          5            teststreet
```

I would like to extract only the first and last record since their combi only occurs once.
The combi field is not needed in the end result, just a way to try to get this to work.

My code:

```
SELECT
[Perceel.lengtegraad] & [Perceel.breedtegraad] As Combi,
Pcreeks.wijkcode, 
Pcreeks.lettercombinatie, 
[huisnr] & " " & [huisnr_bag_letter] & " " & [huisnr_bag_toevoeging] AS 
HnrLetter, 
Straat.straatnaam
FROM 
(Provincies 
INNER JOIN (Plaats 
INNER JOIN ((Gemeente 
INNER JOIN Pcreeks 
ON
Gemeente.gemeenteid = Pcreeks.gemeenteid) 
INNER JOIN Perceel 
ON 
Pcreeks.reeksid = Perceel.reeksid) ON (Gemeente.gemeenteid = 
Plaats.gemeenteid) AND (Plaats.gemeenteid = Pcreeks.gemeenteid) AND 
(Plaats.plaatsid = Pcreeks.plaatsid)) ON Provincies.provincicode = 
Pcreeks.provinciecode) INNER JOIN Straat ON (Pcreeks.straatid = 
Straat.straatid) AND (Plaats.plaatsid = Straat.plaatsid) 
where Pcreeks.wijkcode = "1234" AND Pcreeks.lettercombinatie = "AA";
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: What is the primary key of `Perceel` table? 

Did you try GROUP BY  / HAVING ?

Comment: Hi thanks for responding. Primary key of perceel is perceelid. When i put in a group by nothing seems to happen and if i put in having then access gives me an error (srry, REAL noob here :)

Answer (score 0):

This is not most elegant but you can repeat same query to filter only groups having one element.

```
WHERE Combi IN (
  SELECT Combi FROM (<PASTE_YOUR_QURY_HERE>) AS something
  GROUP BY Combi
  HAVING count(*) = 1
)
```

PS. this is also not good for performance - you should modify the subquery to remove unnecessary joins).

Comment: Ok, I tried t simplify this to get my head around it... this code:
    SELECT Count([Perceel.lengtegraad] & [Perceel.breedtegraad]) AS 
    aantal, Pcreeks.wijkcode, Pcreeks.lettercombinatie, 
    [Perceel.lengtegraad] & [Perceel.breedtegraad] AS Combi
    FROM Perceel INNER JOIN Pcreeks ON Perceel.reeksid = 
    Pcreeks.reeksid
    WHERE (((Pcreeks.wijkcode)="1234") AND 
    ((Pcreeks.lettercombinatie)="AA"))
    GROUP BY Pcreeks.wijkcode, Pcreeks.lettercombinatie, 
    Perceel.breedtegraad, Perceel.lengtegraad
    HAVING (((Count(Perceel.breedtegraad))<2));

Comment: Now i get one adress, but if i add a field, it goed back to all adresses in the 1234AA range..